# Why a given block of code is not reached at all in my report program?

Tags: abap

I am working on a project in which there are two options in the selection screen.

Block Title - Search

1. Flight Information
2. Customer ID

On choosing the first radio button, the following fields may be entered:

CARRID, CONNID, FLDATE (A, B, C)

which gives the first report, and on choosing the second radio button, the following fields may be entered:

CUSTOMER ID (D)

which should give the second report.

With the first radio button some lines are correctly output, but with the second one the program does not even go up to the line `IF rad2 = 'X'` and so nothing is output.

Does someone know why this block of code is not executed?

Code:

```
TABLES : sbook.
DATA : it_final     TYPE TABLE OF sbook,
       wa_final     LIKE LINE OF it_final,
       it_rad2final TYPE TABLE OF sbook,
       wa_rad2final LIKE LINE OF it_rad2final.
PARAMETERS rad1 RADIOBUTTON GROUP rad USER-COMMAND abc DEFAULT 'X'.
SELECT-OPTIONS :
  a FOR sbook-carrid MODIF ID ra,
  b FOR sbook-connid MODIF ID ra,
  c FOR sbook-fldate MODIF ID ra.
PARAMETERS rad2 RADIOBUTTON GROUP rad.
SELECT-OPTIONS d FOR sbook-customid MODIF ID rb.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  IF rad1 = 'X'.
    SELECT * FROM sbook INTO TABLE it_final
         WHERE carrid IN a AND connid IN b AND fldate IN c.
  ELSEIF rad2 = 'X'.
    SELECT * FROM sbook INTO TABLE it_rad2final WHERE customid IN d.
  ENDIF.

IF rad1 = 'X'.
  LOOP AT it_final INTO wa_final.
    WRITE : / wa_final-fldate , wa_final-passname ,wa_final-luggweight COLOR 6.
    HIDE wa_final-customid.
  ENDLOOP.
ENDIF.

AT LINE-SELECTION.
  CALL FUNCTION 'ZKJ_FNMODMINI' EXPORTING custid = wa_final-customid.

IF rad2 = 'X'. " <=== NO BREAK-POINT STOP, LINE NOT REACHED !
  LOOP AT it_rad2final INTO wa_rad2final.
    WRITE :/ wa_rad2final-connid , wa_rad2final-fldate , wa_rad2final-bookid.
  ENDLOOP.
ENDIF.
```

Comment: What means "not working"? Something in the display, or something in the selected data, what exactly?

Comment: You are dooing a LOOP on the rad2final internal table, but the WRITE (right after, before last line) is outside of the LOOP-ENDLOOP. This might not have been your intention...

Comment: @JózsefSzikszai even if i write the WRITE statement inside the loop on execution it is not not printing any thing on the screen

Comment: @Anoopkrishnan than you have to debug... Does the SELECT selects any data? Is your selection criteria OK. Does the DB table hold any data? etc...

Comment: @JózsefSzikszai for the first radio buttion select is happening but for the second radio buttion select is not happening

Comment: Just tested, lots of lines are output. If I expect the program to output lines, then "it works". So, you risk the [question to be put on hold](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) if you don't mention the [**"expected behavior"**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) clearly.

Comment: @SandraRossi ok let me be clear. there are 2 radio buttons. first radio button has 3 select option and 2nd radio button has 1 select option. the part with the first radio button works perfectly but if i choose the second radio button and  enter a value to D (select option) that part doesnt give me a output.

Comment: @SandraRossi full code [here](https://del.dog/javikatoko)

Comment: @Anoopkrishnan the code, you have just posted: the AT LINE SELECTION is now in the middle, move it to the end. If still nothing appears, than you have to check in your system what are in tables SCARR and SBOOK and compare this with the selection criteria you enter on the selection screen (SELECT-OPTIONS d). Seriously, you have to debug, then you see immediately, which step does not work. We cannot tell it from our side...

Comment: @JózsefSzikszai thankyou that soved the issue

Comment: Thank you for the code, and good that it's solved. As per Stack Overflow rules, could you update your question to include the relevant code in Stack Overflow, and keep it [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Thx.

Comment: I have edited the question so that it complies Stack Overflow. Please check whether it's okay for you and edit it if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement **AT LINE-SELECTION** defines an [event block](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenevent_blocks.htm) for the function code `PICK`. Everything following this statement will be executed when this event is triggered (unless other event statements or similar follow).

What you need to do is to move the statements of the block `IF rad2 = 'X'` below the `START-OF-SELECTION` event block.

Comment: is it possible to use at Line-selection inside a if statement

Comment: @Anoopkrishnan No, that is not possible. You have to check relevant variables in the block itself. Like IF rad1 = abap_true. ENDIF.

Comment: I have asked the OP to edit his question to make it a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).